# Autofac register a class which is created by another class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

We have a large ASP.NET MVC application in which we use Autofac for IoC.

Our project contains a service called StoreInformationService which is useful for retrieving all kinds of information about our store.

StoreInformationService has a property called OpeningHours which returns a class called OpeningHours, which is used frequently in many controllers.

I want to register OpeningHours with Autofac so that our controllers can just accept OpeningHours in their constructors, and not concern themselves with the StoreInformationService.

```
public MyController {

    OpeningHours openingHours;

    public MyController(OpeningHours openingHours) {
        this.openingHours = openingHours;
    }

    ...

}
```

I have achieved this with a rather messy RegistrationSource, but I feel there must be a simple way of doing this which I have overlooked?

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it

```
        builder.Register<OpeningHours>(c =>
        {
            var cc = c.Resolve<StoreInformationService>();
            return cc.OpeningHours;
        });
```